# running batch script in java program

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, resources, command

In my eclipse project, I am trying to run system commands, I have collected them in a bash and put it in my project folder.

The java code part is:

```
public static int exportDBMainData(String DBName, String UserName,
            String Password, String FilePath) {

        // First
        String executeCmd = GraphEditor.class
                .getResource("/src/sau/se/editor/recover/semapExport.bat")
                + UserName + " " + Password + " " + DBName + " " + FilePath;
        Process runtimeProcess = null;
        try {
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int processComplete1 = -1;
        try {
            processComplete1 = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return processComplete1;
    }
```

When I run the application I get that error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nullroot": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I fixed partly the problem, now I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "file:/F:/SEMAP_PROJECT/PHASE_1/ECLIPSE_KEPLER/Workspace/SeMap_Recover1.0/bin/sau/se/editor/recover/semapExport.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You say it's a bash script yet it has a .bat extension...

Comment: I'd wager that you're having a problem with your `getResource()` call. Try printing out `executeCmd` to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

With Runtime.exec you don't execute a shell command line but a real executable, optionally with arguments using a String[] cmdArray instad of a String.
So you can't execute the bat line by line, but you can execute it directly with runtime exec:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
   "c:\\program files\\...\\semapExport.bat"
   ,UserName, Password,DBName,FilePath
 });
```

of course the bat file has to be a real file and not a resource in a jar.

Comment: I didn't work, in addition, i will deliver it in a jar and it has variables as u see

Comment: I should work, like i said, the bat file must be in filesystem, try to put it in a c:\tmp directory for test, i will update my answer for arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer that I should call the script via a program, it can not call itself, so I fixed it like that and it has worked:

```
String executeCmd = "cmd /c start "
                + DBUtils.class
                        .getResource("/sau/se/editor/recover/semapExport.bat")
                + " " + UserName + " " + Password + " " + DBName + " "
                + FilePath;
```

Comment: It executes the bat in your workspace because you have a "classes" directory in eclipse. It will not work when packaged in a jar.